# <p:schedule> decode method does not invoke

Tags: java, jsf, schedule, primefaces

I have a problem with `<p:schedule>` component. Its event listeners does not get fired. I have tried to debug and I saw that the component's decode method is not called when I click on an event or day or when I am moving an event. Why is the decode not called? what is responsible for calling it? What should I do to fix this problem?

---

**Update**: I am a step further: the Ajax request is made but it seems that it is not processed by the server. I have tried this by TamperData firefox plugin this is the request:

```
Host=localhost:7001
User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 AskTbUT2V5/3.8.0.12304 Firefox/3.6.8
Accept=application/xml, text/xml, */*
Accept-Language=en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding=gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset=ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive=115
Connection=keep-alive
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
Referer=http://localhost:7001/CalendarConsole/Calendar.jsf
Content-Length=377
Cookie=JSESSIONID=hT2KM8YT2dLzCWy2FnnvN2hw9Ln1Q0zpf58wmJyTVQYgLWt9Dkw2!1127089955; ADMINCONSOLESESSION=r5XKM8STYlW2dRv2F1yWRsSXFXbGyTFTnhKT5W8drg45102CXx1D!1127089955
Pragma=no-cache
Cache-Control=no-cache
POSTDATA=j_id_id2%3Atitle=&j_id_id2%3Afrom=&j_id_id2%3Ato=&j_id_id2%3AallDay=true&autoScroll=&j_id_id2_SUBMIT=1&javax.faces.ViewState=8EgC7hvJoXWgMHaUZxk5rx66APlnNueyP32ajDxbvc%2Fi5akMf2jX5cVdAfmlUISJ504ZgdgVVdSjU3LichhOlEKC8bYGoFkT&primefacesPartialRequest=true&j_id_id2:j_id_id4=j_id_id2:j_id_id4&primefacesPartialProcess=j_id_id2:j_id_id4&j_id_id2:j_id_id4_selectedDate=1283887800000
```

and this is the response

```
Status=OK - 200
Date=Tue, 31 Aug 2010 10:40:33 GMT
Content-Length=374
Content-Type=text/xml
X-Powered-By=Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
```

Is this of any help?

Comment: As per your previous questions, you're using PrimeFaces 1.0 on JSF 1.2 on Facelets, is this still correct?

Comment: yeah primeface 1.02 and myfaces 1.2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked by using PrimeFaces 1.1 and myfaces 1.2.9!